# How to remove vertical spacing between body text and section title inside paracol?

Tags: paracol

I have a short description as body text and then a section title inside the left column of a paracol.  For some reason paracol adds an empty space between the short description and the section title.  How can I remove the vertical space?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{final}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{Outside the Season:}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \section{Section Title}
    \lipsum[3]
    \switchcolumn
    \section*{\centering CENTERED SECTION TITLE}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space is not added by `paracol` but by the `\section` command.

With `memoir` you can use `\setbeforesecskip{<skip>}`  where the length argument is the space to leave above the section heading.

The default is `\setbeforesecskip{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{final}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeforesecskip{-0.1ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \textcolor{red}{Outside the Season:}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{Section Title}
        \lipsum[3]
        \switchcolumn
        \section*{\centering CENTERED SECTION TITLE}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```